# Java method println being skipped

Tags: java

```
//  out.println(" ");//solution
    for (Utilizador ut : Diretorio.getInstance().getUtilizadores()) {
     String s = ("CLT " + ut.getEndereco() + " " +  ut.getPorto() );
        out.println(s); 
        }
    out.println("END");
    System.out.println("Consulta realizada");
```

So i send this to my out stream, but then in my "in" stream i only receive "END" (if the list only has 1 object) if the list has 2 objects my "in" stream will show only 1 object and then END
Here is my "in"

```
} else if(in.readLine()!=null){
   while((msg = in.readLine())!= null){                      
    System.out.println(msg);
   }
 }
```

Cant understand why one of my "out.println()" is being skipped or simply not shown
Both classes are Threads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this code

```
} else if(in.readLine()!=null){
   while((msg = in.readLine())!= null){                      
       System.out.println(msg);
   }
}
```

when `if(in.readLine()!=null)` is executed a line is read but not printed and then in the `while` loop every `msg = in.readLine()` reads another line and print it.  
But the 1st line is never printed.  
Change it to:

```
} else {
   while((msg = in.readLine())!= null){                      
       System.out.println(msg);
   }
}
```

Comment: And there's no way to stop this loop without closing the socket/server right?

Comment: Actually it wont, the loop keeps going on until the socket is closed

Comment: *the loop keeps going on* meaning? Still printing?

Comment: You can read about the condition in.readline() it doesnt end the loop it stays in that condition until some change happens in the socket